# How to highlight usages of method parameter in the IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: intellij-idea, syntax-highlighting, highlight

I know that there is a settings in Editor -> Highlight on Caret Movement -> **Highlight usages of Element at caret**.

But seems it highlight everything else but **method params** in method body.
How can I overcome this?

ps: I use Darcula theme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take the following example:

```
public class Usages {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1 = "x", s2 = "y", s3 = "z";
        new Usages().foo(s1, s2, s3);    // ***
    }

    public void foo(String a, String b, String c) { }
}
```

Are you expecting to hover over `s1` in the line marked `***` and see `a` highlighted in the method parameter for `foo` ?

Unfortunately, that's not going to happen since method parameter `a` doesn't have any *usages* per se.

You can verify this - hover the cursor over `a` in the line `public void foo(String a, String b, String c)` and hit <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>f7</kbd>, IntelliJ will say *No Usages in Project Files*.

This is due to the nature of how usages are looked up - they must be defined according to the `PsiTree`, IntelliJ's internal representation of the code structure.

In contrast, if you hover the cursor on `s1` in the line marked `***`, you will see `s1` highlighted on the line `String s1 = "x", s2 = "y", s3 = "z";` and, similarly, if you hit <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>f7</kbd>, IntelliJ will confirm that there is an `s1` usage on the line above.

Incidentally, there is a plugin that may interest you that works via text-equivalent search (instead of the PsiTree / find usages): [FindWordAtCaret Plugin](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/201?pr=idea)

**Edit**

This works for me. I wonder why doesn't it work for you? IntelliJ 13.1.1

```
public void foo(String a, String b, String c) {
    String bar = a;    // ***
}
```

(Place cursor on `a` on line marked `***` - the `a` from `String a` is highlighted).

Can you try creating a new class file in a new intellij project with this `foo` method? Perhaps it has something to do with the source, or the project.

Comment: No, probably I explained not clear. From your example, I expect when placing a cursor (caret) on the 'a' I see the usages of 'a' highlighted in the body of method foo().

Comment: Yes, that's exactly my case (in your Edit) which doesn't work for me for some reason. Don't know why. Idea 13.0.1. Something wrong with project settings or so, will try to find the reason. Thanks for your help.